# Xamarin iPad app never gets past default blue xamarin logo screen

Tags: ios, xamarin

(Microsoft Windows 10 VS2022)

I have a basic Xamarin App that I have been working with and deploying on my Android Phone. (works great on Android.)

I created a Apple Developer Account and added those details into Visual Studios 2022.

I plugged in an iPad and started debugging.

The app launches and Hot Reload at the bottom says Launch succeeded.

But the screen only shows the Blue default Xamarin page that initially loads as default. It never goes past that - I don't get any errors. And all my breakpoints set at all spots on the App.xaml.cs page and AppShell.xaml.cs page never get triggered.

Is it a navigation issue with my AppShell.xaml.cs?

Or what could I be missing? Where do I look to see where it is hanging?

```
public App()
{    
    MainPage = new AppShell();
}

public partial class AppShell : Xamarin.Forms.Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));      
    }
}
```

Comment: what do the logs show?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I may have found the solution.

I updated the iPad (only one revision back; it's at 15.4 now)… I don't think that was the issue.

I think I had not "Built" the app prior to debugging. This resulted in a bad version being stored on the iPad. (You must delete the app with each change.)

To help - If you have a Windows machine developing on Apple iOS:

When developing on a Windows (win) 10 machine.  You have to do a full build First!

- Build - Build Solution.
- Then debug/deploy on apple device.
- Every change made - you must delete the app off the Apple device, Build, and re-deploy. This is the only way I can get it to work.